# How to make ::WriteFile work in UNICODE circumstance?

Tags: c++, unicode, mfc, mbcs

This code below doesn't work correctly since my MFC program is in unicode circumstance.

```
::WriteFile(hFile, TEXT("123456"), lstrlenW(TEXT("123456")), &dwByte, nullptr);
::CloseHandle(hFile);
```

The result is "123", which is supposed to be "123456"

I found on the internet that Unicode BOM could solve this. 
So I modified my code to go like this below.

```
WORD Unicode = 0xfeff; // UNICODE BOM
::WriteFile(hFile, &Unicode, 2, &dwByte, nullptr);
::WriteFile(hFile, TEXT("123456"), lstrlenW(TEXT("123456")), &dwByte, nullptr);
::CloseHandle(hFile);
```

However, it doesn't make any difference.

Seems like it's a simple problem but I am lost looking for the solution to this.

Any idea would be more than welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Writefile` does not write "text": it write "Bytes".
The `lstrlenW` returns the number of `wchar_t`. 
You shold multiply by `sizeof(wchar_t)` in order to give to the third parameter  the "number of **bytes** to write"

Comment: `TEXT()` operates on `char` or `wchar_t` depending on whether UNICODE is defined, but `lstrlenW()`only operates on `wchar_t`. If you want the code to operate in both environments, use `lstrlen()` and `sizeof(TCHAR)` instead, eg: `WriteFile(hFile, TEXT("123456"), lstrlen(TEXT("123456")) * sizeof(TCHAR), ...)`

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Right again... nice one!

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use `lstrlenW` to determine the amount of data to write -- you need to tell `WriteFile` the number of bytes to write, not the number of code points. Right now, you're telling it 6, which is enough bytes for 3 characters.